# Would any changes made to CPU freq in Ubuntu would apply when Windows is booted in a dual boot?

Tags: ubuntu

I made some changes to the cpu freq in ubuntu, would it be applied in windows?

Comment: I think you should ask this question on a different site, for example superuser.com (another StackExchange site).

Answer (score 1):

No. CPU frequency is controlled by the kernel CPU frequency scaling driver (`cpufreq`) and is not persisted in the firmware. So it will not be applied in Windows unless you run it as a guest operating system hosted in Linux using some sort of virtualization software.